# Adding CorsConfiguration in Cloudformation yaml

Tags: aws-cloudformation

A week ago we created a bucket through the pipeline, and it worked properly. This was the code:

```
Resources:

  ArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  PublicArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: mybucket
```

However we realized that we need some CorConfiguration so I went ahead and added these lines:

```
Resources:

  ArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  PublicArtifactBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: mybucket
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
          - AllowedHeaders:
              - "*"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
            AllowedOrigins:
              - "*"
            MaxAge: "3000"
```

I push the change but I keep getting this error:

```
Embedded stack xxx was not successfully updated. Currently in
UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS with reason: The following resource(s) failed
to update: [PublicArtifactBucket]


Action execution failed
Failed to update stack. Current status: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE. Reason: No reason was provided.
```

Why is this happening and how do i resolve this.

Comment: You should check the stack at
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation

to see what errors you have in the events tab. I tried what you wrote above and it works fine

Comment: Thanks. We were able to figure it out by adding  `PutBucketCORS` under `CloudFormationExecutionRole`